# 9 patch image not working

Tags: java, android

Here is the image: [image: Here is the image]

It seem to be working fine in Eclipse, i.e. button is resized as expected and black bars are not shown. However in the emulator it shows up with black bars and stretched.

Image is saved as `<name>.9.png`. I am using API 10 for both IDE and emulator.

Any clues to what might be the problem?

Comment: Are you also using other 9patches that are actually working or is this the only one? Also, how are you using it exactly?

Comment: @leenephi No, this is the only one. There will be more once I get this one working. It is set as a background for ImageButton view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 1 px boarder needs to be either black or transparent. It looks like the left hand boarder is black and not transparent.

Comment: ah you are correct, there is a bit of semi-transparent residue around black bars. Weird that it worked in IDE though.